# Exploit apache2 service as member of www-data group

Tags: linux, privilege-escalation, ctf

I am attempting to solve a CTF challenge where I am logged in as a member of the www-data group and the apache2 service is misconfigured and can be run as sudo without a password. What I am attempting to do is access a token stored at `/root/token.txt`. From what I can gather I need to get apache2 to run a shell script with it's elevated privileges on start-up. The file `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf` reads:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>

    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

So I tried to write shell script to `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` but I didn't have permission, I also don't have permission to edit the `serve-cgi-bin.conf` file so I can't point the `cgi-bin` at a different directory.

Comment: Which command can you run with `sudo`? One alternative would be to write your own apache config, with paths that you have write access to...

Comment: @vidarlo The way the CTF question is asked it has multiple parts, one part asks "What service can be run as sudo without a password?" To which the correct answer is `apache2`, however, `sudo apache2` still asks for a password and `apache2` returns the error:
`Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to ServerRoot.`
How would I change the config to be the one that I have written?

Comment: You would have to look into what command you can run, and how to pass parameters to that command. `man apache2` will likely give you hints.

Comment: @vidarlo I copied the entirety of /etc/apache2/ into a directory I have write access to in the hopes of supplying the new `apache2.conf` with the `-f` flag, and after changing my by running `source envvars` I now recieve the error `make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80`. So I changed the listen port in `ports.conf` to `81` but I am still recieving the same error about attempting to bind to port 80.

Comment: You'll have to learn the tool you're using. In this case some *nix (probably Linux) and Apache.

Comment: You can't edit the existing file, but did you check if you can add a conf file?

Answer (score 0):

The `if` conditional toward the bottom implements `+ExecCGI` and `+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` which should be able to be used with `find . -exec /bin/sh | (Insert Shell arguments for SymLink Cross-Compiler in C to pipe mod_cgi.c to SymLink and Cross Compile a Rootkit or Linux Kernel Module in a single frame cgi data layer injected into Memory and Processed GPU only)

The `find . -exec` implements system level privileges to run the execution cycle of a compiled binary application in C and if you thread it in a GPGPU you should be able to patch a Rootkit out of the characters in their index locations after reading a file stream and coding a syntactic lexicon as a dictionary key: value array and create a link list compilation and kernel build before using the system privileges for the `/usr/bin/cgi_lib` directory after piping all commands through either `find . -exec /bin/sh |`  or directly through the `find . -exec`  command to elevate privileges enough to use the directory privileges at system level which allow a `cgi` execution and a `SymLink with User Access Role Authenticity for authenticated accounts on local system connections.